# COUNTUNIQUE(range) vs COUNT(UNIQUE(range)) in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Whats the difference between
COUNTUNIQUE(range) and COUNT(UNIQUE(range)) in google sheets?

COUNTUNIQUE(range) is giving more values than COUNT(UNIQUE(range))

was expecting to get same results in both. Because COUNT(UNIQUE(range)) is aslo same isnt it? i.e first get unique values and then count them ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObEDl.png)

Comment: Put samples and show discrepancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difference is that COUNTUNIQUE counts any unique values,

> COUNTUNIQUE Counts the number of unique values in a list of specified values and ranges.

COUNT on the other hand

> COUNT Returns the number of numeric values in a dataset.

̶Y̶o̶u̶ ̶p̶r̶o̶b̶a̶b̶l̶y̶ ̶h̶a̶v̶e̶ ̶a̶ ̶c̶e̶l̶l̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶a̶p̶o̶s̶t̶r̶o̶p̶h̶e̶ ̶w̶h̶i̶c̶h̶ ̶g̶e̶t̶s̶ ̶t̶r̶e̶a̶t̶e̶d̶ ̶a̶s̶ ̶a̶ ̶t̶e̶x̶t̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶i̶g̶n̶o̶r̶e̶d̶ ̶b̶y̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶C̶O̶U̶N̶T̶ ̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ You have text values in your column, they are ignored by COUNT function.

Answer (score 0):

You have a range containing a mixture of numbers and text, so `count` is ignoring the text values. `countunique(range)` doesn't distinguish between numbers and text, so is logically equivalent to `counta(unique(range))`

Comment: yes, i understand. Thanks for counta(unique(range)) too.